# When to use GUIDs for Security?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to MVC and am interested in keeping my MVC app secure.  One of my concern areas, for example, is an Approve page that is available to uses to approve items that are up for review.  The issue is that certain users can only approve certain items.  When approving the app posts the ID of the item being approved to an ApproveItem ActionResult in the controller.  The issue is that in theory (e.g. with FireBug) someone might post random IDs to this ApproveItem controller (including items that they might not be allowed to approve).  Instead of trying to catch every issue like this in filtering, why not just use a GUID as the ID?  Then I am almost 100% certain that the user is only approving an item that they are allowed to approve.

What do you guys use for security in regard to situations like this?  It seems to me that a GUID would be the simplest.  What do you think?

Comment: This appears to be off topic for Stack Overflow, but a great question for [Programmers.stackexchange.com - a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Another good site might be [Information Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: GUIDs are not secre, just unique. Protect your Actions with proper authorization. It's almost all done for you already.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (or at least the tile) doesn't really make sense. You can use Guids for Globally Unique Identifers within a security system, but you shouldn't use them AS the security system.

@ePezhman alludes to a potential [Insecure Direct Object Reference vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference) but this isn't an issue if you are correctly validating your users` actions.

What you're suggesting is [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Your app isn't actually secure, it's just really hard to guess some naughty input. What you should be doing is what you're trying to avoid and validate that the current user has the required permissions to perform the action on the entity. That is, is the user allowed to approve the item? and if they aren't you should display an error message or take other appropriate action (logging the attempt, notifying an administrator etc?).

Answer (score -1):

GUID will be very simplest way to achieve this.
Otherwise you can go for "person -roles " level security to approve your items.